# Is there a way to print a py file in color?

Tags: python, printing

using 2.5.4 on windows 7
is there a simple way to print py files in color (as they appear on the screen) AND select a desired font?

thanks
Glen

Comment: that would depend on your text editor I guess ...

Comment: [pygments](http://pygments.org/)?

Comment: I've seen my fair share of perplexing questions, but...

Comment: There's a number of syntax-highlighting sites. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IDLE, the default IDE that comes with Python for Windows you should be able to print your Python script with syntax highlighting from there.

If you are looking for a script that takes a python file and then prints it with syntax highlighting, you'd need to provide more information as to what you are trying to achieve.